# Generating programs with Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to auto-generate some programs with Haskell. What is the best architecture for this, which enforce semantic rules with the type system, or other haskell-cleverness? Otherwise I would just have lists of statements:

```
type program = [Statement]
data Statement = 
   Variable x |
   IfStatement Condition [Statement] |
   ...
```

Comment: What kind of semantic rules are you looking to enforce? It's possible to use [GADTs to enforce some rules such as simple type checking](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT), but you'll have to elaborate some more on what you're trying to accomplish to get a more specific answer.

Comment: Which language are the programs to be generated supposed to be written in?

Comment: What semantic rules are you seeking to enforce?

Answer (score 8):

If you mean you are generating haskell, check out [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'll like to have a look at [HStringTemplate](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HStringTemplate). It could help if You are already experienced with "StringTemplate" (which was implemented in Java initially?).